# Get list of user groups with Facebook API issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API to get the user groups but the response object is not returning any array or something containing the user groups.

I checked if I'm connected to some groups (public and private) and yes, I'm.

Below is the code:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_location,user_groups" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use `user_managed_groups`, and that will only get you the groups the user is an admin of. `user_groups` you will not get approved in review, as the documentation clearly states.